# Java GUI calculator wont do the calculation

Tags: java, user-interface

Ok so I am trying to create a simple calculator with two JTextField for two numbers, three CheckBoxes so the user can choose sum,difference or multiply, a (Kryej Veprim (so that when this button is clicked if the user for example checked "shuma" at the other JTextField result(rezultati) will display the sum of these two numbers).
Something is totally wrong I know because I cant connect checkboxes with "kryejveprim" button.Any help?
P.s (When I run this code i write numbers but nothing happens when i check the checkboxes or when i click the button)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener,ItemListener{


JTextField numri1,numri2;
JCheckBox shuma,diferenca,shumezimi;
JButton veprimi,ok;
JTextField rezultati;
double n1,n2;
String n1tekst,n2tekst;

public Calculator(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    numri1=new JTextField(10);
    add(numri1);

    numri2=new JTextField(10);
    add(numri2);

    shuma=new JCheckBox("Shuma");
    add(shuma);

    diferenca=new JCheckBox("Diferenca");
    add(diferenca);

    shumezimi=new JCheckBox("Shumezimi");
    add(shumezimi);

    veprimi=new JButton("Kryej Veprimin");
    add(veprimi);

    rezultati=new JTextField(10);
    add(rezultati);

    ok=new JButton("OK");
    add(ok);

    numri1.addActionListener(this);
    numri2.addActionListener(this);
    rezultati.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==numri1)
    {
        n1tekst=e.getActionCommand();
        n1=Double.parseDouble(n1tekst);
        }

    else if(e.getSource()==numri2) 
    {
        n2tekst=e.getActionCommand();
        n2=Double.parseDouble(n2tekst);
    }
}
public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e )

{

 if (e.getSource() == shuma)
   {
     String rez = shuma.isSelected() ? ""+(n1+n2) : "";
     rezultati.setText(rez);
   }
 else if (e.getSource() == diferenca)
 {
   String rez = diferenca.isSelected() ? ""+(n1-n2) : "";
   rezultati.setText(rez);
 }
 else if (e.getSource() == shumezimi)
 {
   String rez = shumezimi.isSelected() ? ""+(n1*n2) : "";
   rezultati.setText(rez);
 }
}
public static void main (String args[])

{

 Calculator ob = new Calculator();
 ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 ob.setSize(900,900);
 ob.setVisible(true);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Well, at the very end of your code you have an empty `actionPerformed()` method.  Makes me think that you might not have filled in that method properly.

Comment: If I delete it this comes out --> The type Calculator must implement the inherited abstract method 
  ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Comment: But why is it empty?

Comment: You have two of these `public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e)`. You don't need both in there, and that's probably why you are not getting what you want

Comment: It wont work if I delete the last one it comes out with what I have written above

Comment: Ok I removed the empty public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) but stillwont work

Comment: Now please add the `Override` annotation to the `actionPerformed()` method that you do have, and repost the code as it stands after that.  Something is very fishy with the syntax here, we'll probably need to inspect it closely.

Comment: you have a typo **actionPerfomed** instead of **actionPerformed** (missing 'r').  if you fix the typo, also add `shuma.addItemListener(this);
     diferenca.addItemListener(this);
     shumezimi.addItemListener(this);` lines in order to activate `itemStateChanged` then the code will kind of work .. however, you should definitely rethink / rewrite your code as  `actionPerfomed` is not suitable for the for the `numri1` and `numri2` Text Fields (as there may be no action performed whatsoever)

Comment: Tried it. Yeah now when i Check a checkbox there is  result but the result is always zero. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes because you use actionPerformed to do the calculations ... try the following enter a number into `numir1` - hit enter (to perform an action) , enter number into `numir2` - hit enter again - then check `shuma`... but as i said you should fix your code's logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused where to put ActionListeners - they belong on components like buttons where you expect an action, and ItemListeners which belong to the check boxes.  Once you sort this out your code will work.  This code will update the result if you press any of the operations, or the result button.

Working code:

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

JTextField numri1, numri2;
JCheckBox shuma, diferenca, shumezimi;
JButton veprimi, ok;
JTextField rezultati;
double n1, n2;
String n1tekst, n2tekst;

public Calculator() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    numri1 = new JTextField(10);
    add(numri1);

    numri2 = new JTextField(10);
    add(numri2);

    shuma = new JCheckBox("Shuma");
    add(shuma);
    shuma.addItemListener(this);

    diferenca = new JCheckBox("Diferenca");
    add(diferenca);
    diferenca.addItemListener(this);

    shumezimi = new JCheckBox("Shumezimi");
    add(shumezimi);
    shumezimi.addItemListener(this);

    veprimi = new JButton("Kryej Veprimin");
    add(veprimi);
    veprimi.addActionListener(this);

    rezultati = new JTextField(10);
    add(rezultati);

    ok = new JButton("OK");
    add(ok);

}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    n1 = Double.parseDouble(numri1.getText());
    n2 = Double.parseDouble(numri2.getText());
    if (e.getSource() == shuma) {
        String rez = shuma.isSelected() ? "" + (n1 + n2) : "";
        rezultati.setText(rez);
    } else if (e.getSource() == diferenca) {
        String rez = diferenca.isSelected() ? "" + (n1 - n2) : "";
        rezultati.setText(rez);
    } else if (e.getSource() == shumezimi) {
        String rez = shumezimi.isSelected() ? "" + (n1 * n2) : "";
        rezultati.setText(rez);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == veprimi) {
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(numri1.getText());
        n2 = Double.parseDouble(numri2.getText());
        if (shuma.isSelected()) {
            rezultati.setText("" + (n1 + n2));
        } else if (diferenca.isSelected()) {
            rezultati.setText("" + (n1 - n2));
        } else if (shumezimi.isSelected()) {
            rezultati.setText("" + (n1 * n2));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])

{
    Calculator ob = new Calculator();
    ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ob.setSize(900, 900);
    ob.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Java class to change the background color based on a checkbox, after pressing button:

```
public class Ngjyra extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JCheckBox kuqe, blu;
JButton veprimi, ok;

public Ngjyra() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    kuqe = new JCheckBox("Kuqe");
    add(kuqe);
    blu = new JCheckBox("Blu");
    add(blu);

    veprimi = new JButton("Kryej Veprimin");
    add(veprimi);
    veprimi.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == veprimi) {
        if (kuqe.isSelected()) {
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (blu.isSelected()) {
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[])

{
    Ngjyra ob = new Ngjyra();
    ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ob.setSize(900, 900);
    ob.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Wow,it worked thanks a lot mate. Just one question if you dont mind. Is there a way so that the result wont show until I click the button? I mean for example I check the JCheckBox shuma but nothing will display on the result unless I click the button.

Comment: Yes, no problem.  You can remove the ItemListener so that nothing happens shuma is chosen.  Comment out the line shuma.addItemListener() ... Let me know how it goes.  Of course do this with the other two operations as well.  This makes the itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) unnecessary.

Comment: If possible could you help me with this too? Its kinda similar. I have two checkboxes with two color and a button to complete the action. When i check a checkbox and click the button the color of the foreground of the whole frame should change based on that color.-->>

Comment: JCheckBox kuqe,blu;
    JButton veprimi,ok;
 public Ngjyra() {
     setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     kuqe = new JCheckBox("Kuqe");
     add(kuqe);
     kuqe.addActionListener(this);
... same for all three other components  }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{if (e.getSource() == veprimi) {
if (kuqe.isSelected()) {
 setForeground(Color.RED);}
else if (blu.isSelected()) {
 setForeground(Color.BLUE); }
     
     }

Comment: Cant post anymore questions reached my limit :/

Comment: Didn't seem to work (the number would increase to "1"), but that is fine.  Glad you like the code and have learned a few things.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you never actually do anything when the calculate (`veprimi`) button is pressed. So maybe add that in your `actionPerformed` method?

Something like:

```
  .... 
   if(e.getSource().equals(veprimi) {
      // calculate value and set result TextField
   } 
   ....
```

Also, you never register any `ItemChangeListener` for the checkboxes, so the method is never called.

Comment: Dont know how to do this part that when button is clicked the program will check what checkbox is checked and give the result based on the checkbox :/ Im new to this,I saw different tutorials online but none of them helped